# How can I make use of jQuery promises in custom async functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So, I've built an api object that can be included in any JavaScript file via require.js. In the api object, I have calls to create Backbone models/collections like the one shown below:

```
getDatapoints: function(attributes, callback) {
    require(['models/datapoint'], function(Datapoint){
        var datapoint = new Datapoint.DatapointCollection(attributes);
        datapoint.fetch({success: function(data){
            return callback(data.toJSON());
        }});
    });
}
```

I want to have a way of being able to start multiple calls and run a callback function once ALL calls have completed. It looks like jQuery's $.when function does what I want, but I'm not sure how to get it to work with anything besides $.ajax calls.

Am I looking in the right place? Should I be looking at something like q.js?

Comment: i don't see how promises would help . aren't they for doing lots of stuff to one process? it seems this is more like doing one thing to many processes. to wit, wouldn't jQuery's promiseses force a stair-step network activity waterfall when fetching many at once?

Comment: @dandavis not necessarily. `$.when.apply($, [fetch1(), fetch2(), fetch3()]).done(dostuff)` would fetch 1 2 and 3 all at the same time, then when all three are finished, `dostuff`. Doing this would just require making getDatapoints return a promise, such as with both of the current answers.

Comment: @KevinB is correct, my answer shows exactly how to do this.

Comment: @KevinB: good info and idea about using apply().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @mattacular's answer:

```
API = {
  getDatapoints: function (attributes){ 
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    require(['models/datapoint'], function(Datapoint){
      var dataPoints = new Datapoint.DatapointCollection(attributes);
      dataPoints.fetch().then(function (points){
        dfd.resolve(points.toJSON());
      }, function (error){
        dfd.reject(error);
      });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
  },
  getAllDatapoints: function (arrayOfAttributes){
    var arrayOfPromises = arrayOfAttributes.map(this.getDatapoints);
    return $.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises);
  }
}
```

And where you're actually calling the `getAllDatapoints` method:

```
var allDatapointAttributes = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
API.getAllDatapoints(allDatapointAttributes).done(function(){
  console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  // should output an array of arrays containing dataPoint
  // objects when all the requests have completed successfully.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery's [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object. Here is a quick example:

```
getDatapoints: function (attributes, callback() { 
   var dataPoints = $.Deferred();

   // perform async calls here
   // when "done," call dataPoints.resolve() or dataPoints.reject() accordingly

   return dataPoints.promise();
}
```

edit: removed outdated tutorial

Comment: The article you linked to is pretty old (almost three years). It mentions the `$.Deferred#pipe()` which I believe is either deprecated or gone altogether. You should be using `$.Deferred#then()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is an old bookmark I pulled. It is outdated. If you have a better link, I will edit my answer but somebody else already elaborated in a different answer so probably isn't necessary.